# В чем заключается суть паттерна EAO?

Tags: java, java-ee, шаблоны-проектирования, ejb

Искал и читал на английском, но смысла так и не понял.

Comment: Если честно первый раз слышу про такой паттерн. Может ты путаешь с [DAO][1] ?


  [1]: http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_Access_Object

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Entity Access Object - это некая вариация на тему старого доброго DAO (Data Access Object), только уже применительно к ентити бинам (EJB) или говоря строго версия DAO с поддержкой операций [CRUD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Create,_read,_update_and_delete) (Create, Read, Update, Delete).

DAO, в свою очередь, это паттерн для разделения кода доступа к данным от бизнес-логики

Comment: уже несколько лет пользуемось этим паттерном, хотя о его существовании я узнал с появлением этого вопроса :)